# Animal models to study depression

Tags: neuroscience, psychology, animal-models, psychiatry

Is there a non-invasive animal model to study the [pathogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathogenesis) (*i.e.,* the development of) depression?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: You might be interested  in [Scientists investigating the DNA outside our genes - the ‘dark genome’ - have discovered recently evolved regions that code for proteins associated with schizophrenia and bipolar disorder.](https://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/clues-to-treatment-of-schizophrenia-and-bipolar-disorder-found) (from the University of Cambridge web site)

Answer (score 5):

**TL:DR: A simple question doesn't usually have a simple answer in science.**

To a great extent, the answer to your question depends on what, exactly, you mean by *non-invasive*. Please know that it is exceedingly difficult to study the pathogenesis of depression by non-invasive methods.

If by non-invasive, you mean the animal is not killed and the brain examined, then yes, there is a great deal of literature studying depression without sacrificing the animal. Blood tests can examine the presence of specific hormones, etc. and imaging studies can see brain changes associated with depression to localize which areas are affected, etc.

But if you consider blood tests to be [*invasive* (which, technically, they are)](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms/def/invasive-procedure), that narrows it down greatly.

In studying animals and depression, the researcher must treat the animal in a way which is highly likely to result in depression, or the study will be fruitless. If you define treating the animal with means that would be considered unethical in humans (or outright cruelty) as invasive, that puts most serious research into the illness outside of the scope of reliability. In designing a study, the researcher must ask themselves, "What events might make an animal become depressed?" It can be as minimally cruel as prolonged social isolation, or can be stepped up to discomfort  (e.g. a repeated shock) when performing pleasant tasks (e.g. eating something tasty), or repeated restraint of an animal significant enough to cause distress, or stepped up to discomfort when performing life-necessitating tasks (getting to food), etc.

If you accept certain stress-inducing events as non-invasive, the researcher can certainly wait until the animal dies of natural causes to do a post-mortem exam, but that becomes problematic in that the more time passes from the event, the more questionable the findings are as related to the event.

If you allow a non-life threatening but technically invasive procedure as acceptable, e.g. a fecal transplant from depressed humans to gut-microbiota-depleted rats to see if depressed behavior occurs due to the gut microbiome, it is still invasive, depending on the definition.

Depression is defined by a number of parameters. Most animal studies will not meet all the criteria to begin with, but a non-invasive one will most likely be *severely deficient* in meeting any of the criteria for pathogenesis of depression.

<sub>PET scans are non-invasive and can be/are used to study depression, but the *pathogenesis* may remain unclear. For example, a dog's beloved caretaker dies, and the dog exhibits clear signs of depression (lack of appetite, energy, anhedonia, etc.) A PET scan will correlate with that seen in humans who suffer deep losses. But, short of waiting for a lot of people beloved by their pets to die and seizing their dogs to do PET scans, it doesn't give us much information that we don't already have in humans or can intuit.</sub>

The link below is a fairly recent (2021) overview of animal models for studying depression and their limitations (including animal-sized imaging machines). Still, the animal must be stressed into depression, which can be considered invasive/inhumane.

All this to say that a simple question doesn't usually have a simple answer in science.

[Benefits of animal models to understand the pathophysiology of depressive disorders](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0278584620303651)